# windows store apps How to bind visibility of an appbar item?

Tags: c#, binding, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have some problems with binding a visibility property of an appbar button.
I want to bind an appbar button visibility to another element visibility.
If the another element is visible - then the appbar is visible.

So here is my code:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btnSave, Path=Visibility}"
                    Click="Edit_Click" />
             ...(more buttons)
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>

<Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"
     x:Name="btnSave"
     Content="Save"
     Style="{StaticResource EditModeButtonStyle}"
     Click="Save_Click" />
```

I am changing the btnSave visibility in the code behind and no reaction in the appbar button's visibility. I have even tried to do the same binding with just a textblock, and it worked fine. I have also tried to use converter on the appbar (even thought I don't need) and I saw that the debugger was not reading the converter's methods. I saw some more people wrote similar appbar problems, but nothing of the answers is not helping me. Does someone know how can I do it? (I don't want to use code behind to change appbar visibility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that appbar elements are not seeing the page's elements and hence element binding is not working. I would recommend you to use independent property which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Bind that property to those elements for which you want to set the visibility.

C#

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage4 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility _IsHide;
    public Visibility IsHide
    {
        get { return _IsHide; }
        set
        {
            _IsHide = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsHide");
        }
    }

    public BlankPage4()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnHideAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsHide = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnHello" Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Content="Hello" />
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Text="Hello" FontSize="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Content="Save" />
        <Button Content="Hide All" Click="btnHideAll_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```